# Is Java 1.8.0 required for Grails 2.4.3?

Tags: java, grails

Is Java 1.8.0 required for Grails 2.4.3?

Grails doc found [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#requirements) says java 1.6.0 and above but I am facing issues with my newly created grails app using java 1.7.0_21.

Thanks!

Comment: 1.7 works fine.  but weren't there some breaking changes in java from 1.7.0_21 -> .25.  Can you update to latest 1.7?

Answer (score 2):

> Is Java 1.8.0 required for Grails 2.4.3?

No.  1.8 is definitely not required by 2.4.3.  It is supported, but not required.

> ...but I am facing issues with my newly created grails app using java
>   1.7.0_21

Without knowing the specifics of the issues you are facing I can't say how to resolve them but if you can update to the latest 1.7.x that would be a good starting point.

Comment: note java 1.8u40 + have a breaking change for spring see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880781/incompatible-jvm-in-ggts-eclipse-and-java-1-8

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can use any 1.6.X or 1.7.X version of Java with Grails 2.4.3. Java 1.8.0 is not supported for this version.

Comment: Looks like this file is compiled with java 1.8.0: C:\Program Files (x86)\Grails\grails-2.4.3\lib\org.springframework\springloaded\jars\springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar. From MANIFEST.MF: Created-By: 1.8.0_05-b13 (Oracle Corporation). Will java 1.7.0 work anyway when this jar is used in the grails app?

Comment: You can compile with a higher version than you target, as long as you specify the target range when you compile.

Comment: "Java 1.8.0 is not supported for this version." - That is incorrect.